# R boxplot with several variables - changing variable names on x-axis

Tags: r

I am new to R and having issues figuring out how to plot multiple variables in the same boxplot and have the x-axis display the variable names instead of `1 2 3 4`.

In other words I want `1` to be `Hi_24h`, `2 = Hi_mo`, etc.

```
boxplot(project$Hi_24h, project$Hi_mo, project$Lo_24h, project$Lo_mo)
```

[image: Image of the boxplot in question]

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`boxplot(project, names=names(project))`

if you do not want all of your columns and would like to select them manually  then create a vector:

```
mynames<-c("Hi_24h", "Hi_mo", "Lo_24h", "Lo_mo")
boxplot(project$Hi_24h, project$Hi_mo, project$Lo_24h, project$Lo_mo, names=mynames
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you!